# How do I form a correct SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to pick and find a value from a Table A, depending on some value from Table B. How can I achieve this.

```
Select 
    Ax 
from 
    TableA 
where TableA.Ay = (Select 
                       Bx 
                   from 
                        TableB 
                   where TableB.By = L AND TableB.Bz = M )
```

Comment: what's the relationship between tablea and tableb?

Comment: Parent Child, where TableA as a parent and TableB as Child.
Solutions provided by nbk and scaisEdge are both working.

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what your question really means in terms of the data.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a JOIN

```
Select TableA.Ax 
from TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB ON  TableA.Ay =  TableB.Bx
    AND TableB.By = L 
        AND TableB.Bz = M
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks ok 
the only thing is when you are not sure that Bx only delivers one row as result

```
Select 
    Ax 
from 
    TableA a
where a.Ay IN (Select 
                       Bx 
                   from 
                        TableB b
                   where b.By = L AND b.Bz = M )
```

Or you must Limit the return of table b to 1 row with LIMIT 1

Also the use of aliases is helpful, for better reading and less typing